# Java Jlabel - not displaying text when using setText

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

When modifying lblError I am using set text. It is working in my try catch statements just fine. But when I am running an else statement and it enters the else statement...(I have checked) the setText doesn't make the label display the text I want it to

it works ehn this code is implemented:

```
try {
    Schedule newSched = ScheduleReader.read(text);
    for (int i = 0; i <= newSched.getLastFlightTime(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Flight> flightsAtTime = newSched.getFlights(i);

    for (Flight f : flightsAtTime) {
         s.add(f);
        }
    }
    flights= getArrayList(s);
    displaySchedule();
    lblError.setText("");

   } catch (IOException e1) {
    lblError.setText(IO_MESSAGE);
   } catch (FormatException e1) {
    lblError.setText(FORMAT_MESSAGE);
   } catch (DuplicateFlightException e1) {
    lblError.setText(DUPLICATE_FLIGHT_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work when I do:

```
 else{
        lblError.setText(FLIGHT_NOT_READY);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Just a side note, where is the `if block` ? And you talking about it is not running inside the `else block` .

Answer (score 2):

Then either 1) the else statement is never called or 2) you're calling the method on a different JLabel object from the one displayed.

To test the first, do:

```
else{
   System.out.println("else block called");
   lblError.setText(FLIGHT_NOT_READY);
}
```

To test the second, check to make sure that you've not created a second instance of the class that holds the JLabel.

Otherwise, if you're still stuck, consider giving us more information and code, as I don't think we have enough to be able to tell you with complete confidence what the cause of your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't necessarily just call `setText()` on a visible label and have it take effect immediately -- *especially* if you're not calling it from an event handler. In general, if you change the appearance of a component that's showing on the screen, you must call `validate()` on the component  to force the layout to be updated; in the case of an empty label getting new text, this is definitely going to be required.

EDIT

And @HovercraftFullOfEels also has some good suggestions of other things that might be going wrong.

Comment: I don't think that this is the current problem for the OP, since they state that the JLabel is able to display text in certain situations. So it looks like there's enough real estate available to it to at least display something. I'm gathering that he's seeing no text displayed at all in his malfunctioning situation.